# How to compare session attribute and string java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, string-comparison

I have a session attribute and a same string:

```
    out.println("<br>");
    out.println(request.getSession().getAttribute("token").toString());
    out.println("<br>");
    out.println(hidden_token);
    out.println("<br>");
    out.println(request.getSession().getAttribute("token").toString() == hidden_token);
```

But I get a result which not expected

```
07581d61db9213eb4549b12388f8c106
07581d61db9213eb4549b12388f8c106
false
```

Comment: You are checking whether they are the same object (`==`). Use `equals()` if you want to see if two objects are "equal" (where "equal" means what the specific implementation of the method means). In the `String` implementation of `equals()`, they are considered equal if their contents are the same sequence of characters.

Comment: Same result with an equals :(

Comment: If equals doesn't work, try trimming them: `request.getSession().getAttribute("token").toString().trim().equals(hidden_token.trim())`

Comment: Thanks, it's works now, trim is helpful

Comment: So your unexpected original result (`false`) was right after all: the two strings were different. Leading and trailing spaces are hard to catch by just comparing two strings visually. For this very reason, when I log or print string variables for debug, I almost always print them surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("token").toString().equals(hidden_token)
```

Comment: Could you explain why using `equals` method? Or provide a brief comparison between `equals` and `==`. Single line of code without comments is not useful.